# Weka not display Correctly classified instances and Incorrectly instances in the output

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset, random-forest, weka

[Weka Pre-process tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzoDn.png)

I have added that 1st field is nominal and when I ran my Random-Forest algorithm it gives me the below output without the correct and Incorrect fields.

[Random Forest Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv48K.png)

Dataset Information = https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Crop+mapping+using+fused+optical-radar+data+set

My question is how to get the Correctly and Incorrectly fields in my Weka output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Weka uses the **last** attribute as class attribute. Make sure to select the correct attribute to act as class attribute from the dropdown list on the *Classify tab*.

RandomForest works with numeric and nominal class attributes, either performing regression (what you got in yout output) or classification.